# Joining two CSVs using SQL/ADO in VBA - Invalid Data

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I'm at a loss here. I'm trying to join two CSV tables using SQL via ADO in VBA. The function is to match FX rates against specific dates and currency types. I'm using a string made of the date and currency code as a KEY to try to match these, as joining on matching dates and currency codes didn't work.

Instead of giving the proper FX rate, the code below instead returns 1 or 0.

```
adoRS.Open "SELECT tmpFile.[KEY], fxFile.[KEY], tmpFile.[TRADE_DATE]," & _
    "tmpFile.[CURR_CODE]," & _
    "tmpFile.[VOLUME]," & _
    "tmpFile.[TRADE_PRICE]," & _
    "tmpFile.[CAD_VAL]," & _
    "fxFile.[FX_PRICE]" & _
    " FROM tempFile.csv tmpFile, " & _
    " 2011FXRates.csv fxFile" & _
    " WHERE tmpFile.[KEY]=fxFile.[KEY]", _
    adoCxn, _
    adOpenForwardOnly, _
    adLockReadOnly, _
    adCmdText
```

Oddly, the KEYs match up fine. Why doesn't the FX_PRICE come in as I would expect? Any ideas?

**Sample Data**

From tempFile.csv

```
 KEY    TRADE_DATE  CURR_CODE   VOLUME  TRADE_PRICE CAD_VAL
 40554-000  40554           0   600     1.5         900
 40556-000  40556           0   800     0.75        600
 40556-000  40556           0   1500    0.25        375
 40556-000  40556           0   800     2.8         2240
 40574-000  40574           0   300     1.3         390
```

From 2011FXRates.csv

```
 KEY        TRADE_DATE  CURR_CODE   FX_PRICE
 40554-000  40554       0           1.2605
 40555-000  40555       0           1.1609
 40556-000  40556       0           1.1494
 40557-000  40557       0           1.1362
 40560-000  40560       0           1.128
```

**UPDATE**
I just spotted the problem - it's only taking the first digit on the FX_PRICE, so 1.xxx becomes 1, 0.xxx becomes 0. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not an inner join on date and currency code? Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I tried an inner join on date and currency code and that didn't work either. Will post some data. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Is it possible that you have additional delimiters in the data?  If there was an extra tab inbetween TRADE_DATE CURR_CODE, the 0 or 1's in CURR_CODE could be what you're seeing instead of FX_PRICE.

Comment: The samples you posted are not CSV (comma separated value). They are either fixed width or tab delimited. If you have not specified the right type in your connection string, you will have problems.

Comment: I parsed them to make them more readable. I assure you, they are comma-delimited. There are no tabs, semi-colons, or other commas in these data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's pretty weak to answer one's own question, but, well, I haven't a choice.

The problem turned out that the query was taking only the first digit of the FX_RATES because that's how the numbers appeared at the top of the file - as single digits without any numbers after the decimal place.

**My Solution**

There are a few ways of fixing this. I converted my FX_RATES to text values with 5 digits after the decimal place in Excel `=TEXT(A1, "0.00000")` and then resaved the FX CSV file.

Changing the number formatting to a number with 5 digits after the decimal and resaving the CSV accomplished the same thing.

I suppose this is by design in ADO or SQL...

Comment: It's always fun googling the same problem years after and finding your own question here. Since posting this, I've found another solution, which involves building a Schema.ini file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that specifies the formats of the inputs. This requires a separate file to be located in the same directory as the workbook running the code, which isn't always optimal.